# IBM Worklight 6.1.0.1 - Unable to use local file in Cordova's InAppBrowser in Android?

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

Trying to open a local image using Cordova's InAppBrowser, it fails with an error.
This is my attempt:

```
window.open("file:///storage/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/1398269673199.jpg","_system", "location=no");
```

This is the error in Android 4.3's LogCat:

> 05-05 11:13:14.161: D/InAppBrowser(23539): InAppBrowser: Error loading url file:///storage/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/1398269673199.jpg:android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///storage/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/1398269673199.jpg }

Doing the same, with a URL, works:

```
window.open("www.google.com","_system", "location=no");
```

Does anyone know of a solution?

Comment: Please mention your Worklight version as well as the Android version this is being tested in.

Comment: it is WorkLight 6.1 and Android API 18.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you are from the IBM Maximo team and that you (or someone in your team) has already talked with the IBM Cordova team...

This may be a Cordova defect. To receive a iFix in the meanwhile, open a PMR.
The fix will be available in future Worklight fix packs as well.

Comment: Yes im from IBM Maximo team and will open the PMR. Thanks for help

Comment: @LeonardoLeitedeMelo, did you open a PMR? What is its number?